# Extraindo dados de um data frame no R

Tags: r, loop, for

Tenho um data frame no R e a tabela tem conjuntos de linhas com um mesmo atributo (nome de uma instância) e com diferentes colunas com dados sobre cada instância.

```
INSTÂNCIA   VALOR 1    VALOR 2
Instancia 1  10          20    
Instância 1  34          45
Instância 1  21          43
...
Instância 2  33          24
Instância 2  55          67
Instância 2  65          24
...
```

Como posso fazer para extrair apenas os valores da instância 1 para um dos valores em um vetor, depois a mesma coisa para a Instância 2?

Poderia usar subset do valor e colocar o alcance entre colchetes:

```
subset(data$VALOR1[1:3])
subset(data$VALOR2[4:6])
```

Mas a questão é que tenho 32 instâncias com 100 repetições cada e não queria ter de fazer a mesma operação 32 vezes.

Tem alguma forma de usar um `for` loop para isso e ter na minha rotina de repetições a criação de um `vetor(i)` que armazena a cada interação os 100 valores de cada instância? Assim, depois de 32 iterações, seriam gerados 32 vetores, cada qual com 100 valores para cada Instância.

Answer (score 3):

Pode dividir `data` com a função `split` e depois aplicar a extração das colunas a cada sub-df.

```
sp <- split(data, data$INSTÂNCIA)
result <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
  sp[[i]][, i + 1]
})

names(result) <- names(sp)
result
#$`Instância 1`
#[1] 10 34 21
#
#$`Instância 2`
#[1] 24 67 24

rm(sp)
```

**Dados.**

```
data <- read.table(text = "
INSTÂNCIA   VALOR.1    VALOR.2
'Instância 1'  10          20    
'Instância 1'  34          45
'Instância 1'  21          43
'Instância 2'  33          24
'Instância 2'  55          67
'Instância 2'  65          24
", header = TRUE)
```